# JayData with WebAPI OData V4 returns undefined

Tags: node.js, odata, asp.net-web-api2, aws-lambda

I'm writting AWS lambda function in NodeJS to read the data from WebAPI OData V4 service (http://localhost/SomeService/$metadata)
I generated metadata file using JaySvcUtil and referenced the resulting file in Lambda function

```
'use strict';
let $data = require('jaydata');
let meta = require('./apiData');

exports.handler = function (event, context) {

var con = new DataContext({
    name: 'oData',
    oDataServiceHost: 'http://localhost/SomeService'
});

con.onReady(function () {
    $data.Users.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log(data.Id);
    });;
};
```

Unfortunately, when onReady method is invoked, Users object is undefined as well as any other type exosed by my API.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that generated code created by jaysvcutil doesn't work with nodejs.
Instead of using .extend, .define should be used as explained in the doc.

```
$data.Class.define('Project.User', $data.Entity, null, {
    'UserID': { 'key': true, 'type': 'Edm.Int32', 'nullable': false, 'computed': true },
});

$data.Class.define('$Project.Types.Context', $data.EntityContext, null, {
    Users: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Project.User }
});
```

And context initialization callback should be defined as follows:

```
jayContext = new $Project.Types.Context({
    name: 'oData',
    oDataServiceHost: 'http://localhost/SomeService'
}); 

jayContext.onReady(function (serviceContext) {
    serviceContext.Users.forEach(function (user) {
        console.log(user.UserID);
    });

    context.done(null, 'Hello World');
});
```